# How to perform assert_has_calls for a __getitem__() call?

Tags: python, mocking, python-3.7, python-unittest, assertion

Code:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call

mm = MagicMock()
mm().foo()['bar']

print(mm.mock_calls)
print()

mm.assert_has_calls([call(), call().foo(), call().foo().__getitem__('bar')])
```

Output:

```
[call(), call().foo(), call().foo().__getitem__('bar')]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 9, in <module>
    mm.assert_has_calls([call(), call().foo(), call().foo().__getitem__('bar')])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How to fix this assert?

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug, since you should always be able to use the `repr` output of a `call` object to re-create a new `call` object of the same value.

The problem here is that `call`, an instance of [`unittest.mock._Call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2302), relies on the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method to implement its chained call annotation magic, where another `_Call` object is returned when a non-existent attribute name is given. But since `_Call` is a subclass of `tuple`, which does define the `__getitem__` attribue, the `_Call.__getattr__` method would simply return `tuple.__getitem__` instead of a `_Call` object when the attribute `__getitem__` is asked for. Since `tuple.__getitem__` does not accept a string as a parameter, you get the said error as a result.

To fix this, since the determination of whether or not an attribute is defined is done via the call of the [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method, which raises `AttributeError` when a given attribute name is not found, we can override `_Call.__getattribute__` so that it would raise such an exception when the given attribute name is `'__getitem__'`, to effectively make `__getitem__` "non-existent" and pass on its resolution to the `__getattr__` method, which would then return a `_Call` object just like it would for any other non-existent attribute:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    if attr == '__getitem__':
        raise AttributeError
    return tuple.__getattribute__(self, attr)

call.__class__.__getattribute__ = __getattribute__ # call.__class__ is _Call
```

so that:

```
mm = MagicMock()
mm().foo()['bar']
mm.assert_has_calls([call(), call().foo(), call().foo().__getitem__('bar')])
```

would raise no exception, while:

```
mm.assert_has_calls([call(), call().foo(), call().foo().__getitem__('foo')])
```

would raise:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call(), call().foo(), call().foo().__getitem__('foo')]
Actual: [call(), call().foo(), call().foo().__getitem__('bar')]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/StrikingRedundantAngle

Note that I have filed the [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue37972) at the Python bug tracker and submitted my fix as a [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15565) to CPython, so hopefully you will no longer have to do the above in the near future.